# Eclipse in Ubuntu starting without any window visible (only menu bar)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and Eclipse Kepler. Since yesterday I've been experiencing a strange issue: when I open up Eclipse, all that I'm seeing is the menu bar on the upper Ubuntu bar. No code editor, window whatsoever.

In order to see a window I go to Window -> New window, but this is just a workaround. It starts up a new window with no preferences set, no last edited files etc. Moreover it shows that I have 2 Eclipse windows opened, while I can only see 1.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: add screenshot. You can also share here http://imgur.com

Comment: http://imgur.com/s4JzOjG

Comment: Yes, I've tried Alt-Tab - it's nowhere to be found. I'd like to avoid switching workspace or worse, reinstalling Eclipse, as it's my PC at work and the project configuration took me a long time and I wouldn't like to go through it again. But thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with Gorka, it looks like it was related with window size.

Here my solution (worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04):
1) Switch to Eclipse so that menu header is visible (you can use Alt+Tab or click on Eclipse icon in the list of applications)
2) Press Ctrl+Super+ArrowUp (Super=Windows button usually between Ctrl and Alt)

This combination maximizes active window, so it restores Eclipse to full screen.

Comment: I was running ubuntu on vm on mac. This was the key combination that worked - Ctrl + Cmd + ArrowUp. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Show Toolbar.  That should fix your issue.

Edit: Also try Window -> Close All Perspectives.  Now, Window -> Open Perspective -> Other... and select Java (default).

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these solutions works. When I go to to Window I can only see "Hide Toolbar". Then after I close all perspectives and open up the Java one nothing changes. It's as if the window was invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, the only solution I could find was to download the newest Eclipse version from [www.eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org) instead of from the Ubuntu repository.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I've found out what was happening:

The problem was that the size of the eclipse window had been reduced to the minimum, see my desktop in https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q40n4.jpg and notice the small vertical line in the top-left corner. This small line is the eclipse window, so just go with the cursor and make the it bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem happening on only one workspace I had setup within Eclipse. I pressed some keyboard shortcut to make it happen but didn't know what that shortcut was (fat fingers meant I pressed a key I didn't mean to) and now can't reverse it! All other workspaces loaded up fine.

Managed to resolve it by Clicking on Window -> New Window!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and got to fix it by just maximizing the windows (window button + up arrow key).. lol
stupid, but worked.